# 2 reports on the same mail (Reporting Services)

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

In Reporting Services there is a possibility to add as Subscription an email address where the emails are delivered.

Is it possible to combine 2 or more reports to be sent in the same mail? I don't think that there is a posibility to do this directly but maybe one of you knows a work - around?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to do it through the normal subscription. However, there is an SSIS add-on that can generate SSRS reports (http://ssisreportgenerator.codeplex.com/). If you really needed to do that, you could use that add-on in conjunction with other SSIS functionality to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this directly in a reporting services GUI (Report Manager or Sharepoint).

A possible workaround is to use the scripting utility rs.exe to generate the reports to files e.g. PDF, and then email them using sp_send_dbmail. You can create an email with multiple attachments using sp_send_dbmail, but watch out for the default 1MB file size limit per attachment.